# java.lang.stackoverflowerror error in recursion

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, numbers, java.lang.class

I've been trying to print the numeric pattern 4,5,9,18,34 through recursion but I'm getting java.lang.stackoverflowerror error. Here is my code for your reference.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank You

```
public class pattern3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pattern(4,0,5);
    }
        
    static void pattern(int n,int pos,int z) {
        if(pos==z) {
            return;
        }
        int a=(int) Math.pow(pos,2);
        int b=n+a;
         pattern(b,pos++,z);
         System.out.println(b);
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By swapping the lines `pattern(b, pos++, z);` and `System.out.println(b);`, you'll see that the value of `b` is always `4`. The reason for this is that the argument for `pos` is always `0`. The postfix increment operator (e.g., `pos++`) increments the value but *returns the old value*. Since the first argument for `pos` was `0`, the old value for `pos` will always be `0`.

You need to change:

```java
pattern(b, pos++, z);
```

To:

```java
pattern(b, pos + 1, z);
```